# Android/Appengine "anonymous" access

Tags: android, security, google-app-engine, authentication

I'm planning to develop an Android application with an app-engine backend.
However I would like to refrain from using authentication (either with Google accounts or Open ID). Since the data will be sent only from my app and not any other client, and will be over `SSL connection`, I consider the data safe and trusted.

So my question is two-fold:

- Is there any security issue I'm missing here ?
- All the examples I found use some sort of authentication. Is it at all possible to use the android appengine infrastructure (RequestFactory, etc) without authenitcation ?

Comment: Define "safe and trusted" - what's your threat model? Who are your attackers, and what are they trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An app engine application is just a regular web application deployed on app engine. If you need to authenticate your users, do so. If you don't need to, then don't.

You're missing something, though: once a web app is deployed on app engine, it's accessible from anywhere on the web, and so anyone (and not just your app) could send requests to this application, whether you use SSL or not. SSL will just make the communication encrypted, and ensure the client that they're talking to your web app, and not to a rogue web app maskerading as yours.

Comment: Right, but since I don't provide a web-client front-end, and encrypt the communication with the android app by SSL, do you see any possible vulnerability in this scheme (i.e. can the datastore be compromised)?

Comment: How will you access the GAE app from the android app if you don't provide any web front-end? You'll necessarily provide one. And since you don't need to authenticate to access it, anybody will be able to access it. SSL doesn't authenticate the client. It authenticates the server and encrypts the communication.

Comment: sorry, I meant that I don't provide a web-browser front end.

Comment: If you're able to access the application over the web, any other developer will also. Guessing URLs is not so difficult, especially if the you just have to use your android app and inspect which requests it does.

Comment: sure, but how will he know how to communicate with the server side ? He can't monitor the "real" connection since it's encrypted

Comment: Unless some logging hook can be installed in android's HTTP stack. I don't know if it's possible, but I would only assume that SSL makes the conversation encrypted for a man in the middle, but not for the sender.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Can you please clarify how authentication would have helped for the scenario you're describing ?

Comment: If all the GAE services just throw an exception if they're called by a non authenticated user, then you can't be sure that only you android app accesses the services, but you can know which user does what, and only return sensitive data to authenticated user